# Display Errors manually with simple-form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, simple-form

I am using simple-form for a form. I have switched to using ajax to submit the form, and I would like to validate the form client-side, preventing submission and display any errors. I am currently using binding to ajax:beforeSend and checking all the required fields, but how do I display the helper text and error messages? Do I need to do that manually?

Comment: Don't you reinvents the wheel? Have you looked at https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations? It suports simple form.

Comment: @MikhailD I'm trying to get away from using Gems instead of understanding what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Validity](https://github.com/afincha/validity). It is specifically for doing this.